# Talking over the phone for the first time

Tags: politeness, greetings

I will have an interview in English over the phone, and I am preparing for it.
What I'm wondering is what will be the best way to greet the interviewer?
"Hell, my name is ______. It is nice to talk to you or I am happy talking with you" 
I am confused it because if I meet someone for the first time I can just say it is nice to see you or nice to meet you, but it will be over the phone.....

Help me, please.

Comment: Presumably *they* will be telephoning you?  Presumably they already know your name, so saying "My name is ..." could give the wrong impression.  Why not something like "Thank you for calling." or "Thank you for selecting me for interview." or "It's nice to speak with you ..."?

Comment: Presumably, you mean "Hell**o**, my name is...."

Comment: Define "*best way*". POB.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional English responses to receiving a phone call at home:

- Hello
- X family residence
- This is Xinaho

Traditional English responses to receiving a phone call at work:

- Hello
- You've reached X company, how can I help you?
- This is Xinaho

Even if you say your name they may automatically ask for you by name saying

- Can I speak to Xinaho

Respond by saying

- Speaking
- This is Xinaho

After that just be polite, confident, and enthusiastic.

Comment: There's one other answer even native English speakers have issues with. When the person calling says, "Can I speak to Xinaho?" You may answer, "This is s/he." __Not__ him/her. Or you could say, "Speaking," but it's a bit more informal.